# Dynamics CRM web api 8.2 does not retrieve page cookie in JavaScript call

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm

There is a lot of documentation on how to retrieve more then 5000 records in c#, but not in JavaScript. I need this to work in my CRM web resource JavaScript file.

I have a query:

```
var fetchXML = `
            <fetch mapping="logical" output-format="xml-platform" version="1.0" page="1">
              <entity name="account" >
                <attribute name="name" />
              </entity>
            </fetch>`;

var query = "accounts?fetchXml=" + fetchXML;

callWebAPI(query);
```

This call returns 5000 records. I need to retrieve more (all of them). But this response does not retrieve any page cookies how I can proceed to the next page, or I do not know where to find them.

Where I am wrong here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tested this URL on v9.1: 
`https://myOrg.api.crm.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.1/new_sampledatas?fetchXml=<fetch><entity name='new_sampledata'/></fetch>`

The response includes the FetchXML Paging Cookie[image: pagingCookie]

[This article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dynamicscrm-2016/developers-guide/mt607533(v=crm.8)#paging-with-fetchxml) about v8 mentions that you may have to set a header to request the paging cookie:
A paging cookie must be requested as an annotation. Set the odata.include-annotations preference to use (or include) `Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.fetchxmlpagingcookie` and a `@Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.fetchxmlpagingcookie` property will be returned with the result.

[This article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/org-service/page-large-result-sets-with-fetchxml) shows how to use the FetchXML paging cookie.